# jquery get textarea -> append to search string

Tags: jquery, search, tags, instagram

Im trying to make a search function that gets the value from the text area onclick and then further appends it to as a new image

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".btn").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: false,
        url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/[!!!]beach/media/recent?client_id=xxx&access_token=yyy",
        success: function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                $("#w").append("<a class='photos' target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link + "'><img src='" + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url +"'></img></a>");
            } 
        }
    });
});
```

I would like to get textarea word and append it to the URL section replacing the [!!!] ../tags/[!!!]beach/

any ideas? or is there a more simple way?

Comment: can you provide the html

Comment: sorry,

<div id="w">
<section id="sform">
   <input type="text" id="s" name="s" class="sfield" placeholder="Find a beach" autocomplete="off">
   <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
  </section>
  <section id="photos"></section>
  </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try to get the value by element id

```
var txtarea = $("#s").val();
```

is this u want?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".btn").click(function() {

        var txt = $("#s").val();
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: false,
        url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/"+txt+"beach/media/recent?client_id=xxx&access_token=yyy",
        success: function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                $("#w").append("<a class='photos' target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link + "'><img src='" + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url +"'></img></a>");
            } 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: yes, partly. However, I want to get the value from the textarea and by clicking the btn it will search for that value

Comment: Thank you!
what would you suggest as a solution to research each time the btn is clicked?

Comment: its upto your requirement... according to the code you provided uts better to go with search every time you click submit

Comment: actually, how would I go in doing that?
that after the first time I click, and when retype another phrase into the textarea it will allow for another search?